# Google Tag Manager for Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, google-tag-manager

I've followed the quick start guide [here](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/googleiostagmanager) for setting up Google Tag Manager in my Xamarin.iOS app, but I am receiving an unexpected error when the container initializes:

> GoogleTagManager warning: Error when loading resources from url: https://www.googletagmanager.com/r?id=GTM-XXXXX&v=iXXXXXXXXX status code = 403

I've tried two different valid container ids and they both fail with this error. Providing a random container id presents a different error message.

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by using a "Firebase (iOS)" container with the Google Tag Manager Xamarin component. At the time of this writing, the GTM component for Xamarin is only compatible with "Legacy iOS" containers. After switching to a Legacy iOS container, this error is no longer presented.

[image: Legacy iOS Container]

Comment: Is this still the case? I don't think so since the official [documentation](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/googleiostagmanager) refers to Firebase. I have Firebase working fine, but nothing seems to be routed through GTM after following the official instructions and there is pretty much no information anywhere else on how to use Firebase+GTM. Is GTM not used much for Xamarin apps (or apps in general)?